# Progressed : Convergence problem in Hilbert Space and necessity of inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

******** PROGRESS : so thanks to Ian's great comment I can get by the proof and that completeness is necessary but I need to know does this hold for general Banach spaces that are not Hilbert spaces?

I have this assignment question from Functional Analysis class stating:

> Let $ \mathcal{H} $ be a Hilbert Space with a sequence $ \{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ of elements in $ \mathcal{H} $. There is a constant $ A \in R $ such that for every sequence $ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}  $ satisfying $ 0 \leq |a_n| \leq 1 $ all zero except a finite number of elements, we have ||$ \sum_{n} a_nx_n $|| $ \leq $ A. We are asked to prove $\lim_{N\to\infty} {\sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n}$ exists in the norm. Also, does this hold if the space H is not complete? What about a norm space where the norm is not induced from an inner product?

Last part before this I proved:

> For all $ \{ x_n \}_{n=1}^N \in \mathcal{H} $ there are scalars $ \{ a_n \}_{n=1}^N $ on the complex unit circle such that : $||\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_nx_n ||^2 \geq \sum_{n=1}^{N} ||x_n||^2 $

I don't exactly know how to incorporate that previous part or if I even need to for that matter. I would really appreciate help.

PROGRESS : so thanks to Ian's great comment I can get by the proof and that completeness is necessary but I need to know does this hold for general Banach spaces that are not Hilbert spaces?

Comment: In the first part, you want to show that $y_N=\sum_{n=1}^N x_n$ is Cauchy in the norm. This means that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $B \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $N \geq M \geq B$ then $\| \sum_{n=M}^N x_n \| < \varepsilon$. Of course it is the same to have $\| \sum_{n=M}^N x_n \|^2 < \varepsilon$. Can you control this quantity using your previous result and the boundedness assumption involving $A$?

Comment: @Ian : no Ian that's just it I cannot get over the last result having squares (powers of two) but the task at hand does not

Comment: As I edited into the previous comment, you can force the square into the problem at no loss.

Comment: @Ian : OK I think I can do this now but part of it is still to determine if completeness and the norm being induced from an inner product are necessary?

Comment: @Ian : actually completeness I see is necessary as Cauchy having a limit is completeness but what about the norm not being induced from inner product space? i.e. a Banach space that is not Hilbert

Comment: The argument I suggested fails if you don't have completeness, but to be sure that the *conclusion* also fails if you don't have completeness, you should use some example. Consider $X \subset \ell^2$ where $x \in X$ if and only if all but finitely many entries of $x$ are zero. I'm not so sure about the last part.

Comment: The address the last question, consider the space $\ell^{\infty+}$ of bounded sequences over $\mathbb{N}$ with the standard $\max$ norm and $x_n=e_n$ the canonical unit vectors with all zeros except unity at index $n$.

Comment: @Ian: To be honest, I don't really see how to apply the OPs previous result to conclude the proof. The estimate seems to go in the wrong direction. Different question (directed at zbigniew2015) how did you prove your previous result?